# my scrollview in viewcontroller is not displaying the tableview in the container

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to display the viewcontroller with many labels, tableview with 3 rows and buttons. My container space is not enough so i'm using a scrollview of third party class TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.

Now while running the application in xcode iPhone simulator, my scrollview,label and buttons are displaying, other than my tableview. Also tried this application running on my iphone, the same case exists there, but once I changed my application from portrait to landscape and again to portrait, now my tableview is being displayed. But every time while running my application, i'm in need of changing portrait to landscape.

I can't figure what mistake am doing? Can any one find the solution for this problem? Thanks in advance...

Code

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.h" 

interface preview : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> 
property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton *comment; 
property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton *appove; 
property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton *change; 
property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview; 
property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView *scrollview; - (IBAction)clickedcomments:(id)sender; 
- (IBAction)clickedapprove; 
- (IBAction)clickedchange; 
end
```

Comment: Log to get the frame data of table view. And add that information also to the information. Make sure the nib file you are using for iphone has the tableview positioned correctly inside scroll view.

Comment: @DivyaBhalodiya, preview.h file codes, #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.h"

interface preview : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton *comment;
property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton *appove;

property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton *change;

property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;

property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView *scrollview;

- (IBAction)clickedcomments:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)clickedapprove;
- (IBAction)clickedchange;

end

Comment: @ratul, ya I have positioned the tableview inside the scrollview. My scrollview Attributes of (Key Path)/(Type)/(Value) are contentSize/Size/{320,600} and frame/Rect/{{0,0},{320,600}}

Comment: @sathya : Add your code here means add it to question.You can ad by clicking the edit button which will make the question more defined and you will have better answers

Comment: @ratul, i got my tableview being displayed, thanks for ur help... i didnt set my tableview frame, after setting its value, i got get the expected output

Comment: @DivyaBhalodiya,  i got my tableview being displayed, thanks for ur help... i didnt set my tableview frame, after setting its value, i got get the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are implementing the app in both the orientations. Also the frame setting is done in change orientation method. When the first time the code executes tis setting of frame doesnt happen since orientation call doesnt happen.***Make sure the frame is initally set properly in the IB, else make sure it is set in the `-viewDidLoad` or `-viewWillAppear` method.***

Comment: Ya, application runs in both orientation. My scrollview Attributes of (Key Path)/(Type)/(Value) are contentSize/Size/{320,600} and frame/Rect/{{0,0},{320,600}} and my tableview's attributes are contentSize/Size/{320,400}

Comment: what is the tableview frame ?

Comment: thanks for asking about tableview frame, i didn't set its frame before, now I got get the tableview displaying in my view controller... thnks for u help...